# Find the commit that changed file permissions

Tags: git

What combination of arguments to `git log` or similar will find the commit that changed permissions on a file?

I can use `git log -p <file>` and grep for "new mode", but that doesn't seem very satisfying.

Answer (score 7):

My solution use `git log --summary` and `grep`

List all commits that the permission of a given file is modified

```
git log --summary {file} |grep -e ^commit -e"=>"|grep '=>' -B1 | grep ^commit
```

If `{file}` is omitted, it will list all commits, where any file's permission is modified.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is an option that will directly result in a "changed permissions on file" sort of message, but you can use `git log --raw -- file.sh` and look at the first two columns of the entries for that file, which are the old mode and the new mode. A simple `awk` script could be used to compare the two...

Answer (score 0):

Git doesn't store file permissions. It checks files out with (umask-mediated) 777 for executable files and directories and 666 for ordinary files as demonstrated here (the ls output is truncated of course)

```
$ git checkout empty
$ umask 0
$ git clean -dfx
$ git checkout master
$ ls -l
-rw-rw-rw-  1 jthill jthill   4012 May 13 13:30 tag.c
drwxrwxrwx  2 jthill jthill   4096 May 13 13:30 builtin
-rwxrwxrwx  1 jthill jthill  22332 May 13 13:30 git-am.sh
lrwxrwxrwx  1 jthill jthill     32 May 13 13:30 RelNotes -> Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.2.txt
```

Comment: Mostly correct, it does store two different modes for files: 644 for normal files and 755 for executable files.

Comment: Although it doesn't store user/group/other permissions, it does store executable and symlink bits.

Comment: Gahh, not much excuse for not checking that.

Comment: I've found information on file permissions in repos surprisingly hard to find.  But there is this, from https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html#def_blob_object tree object: An object containing a list of file names *and modes*...

Comment: @gcbenison Yes, Git does track file modes, but it replaces nearly all of them with its own ones. There is `100644` (files), `100755` (executables), `120000` (symlinks), and `040000` (subtrees). But nothing else really. For files, Git only tracks if they are executable or not.

Comment: @poke That's right, and I'm looking for a way to search for the most recent commit that changed the executable permission bit.

Comment: Wow. What's yours do with umask 0?  I just got 666 for files, 777 for executables and directories.

Comment: @jthill When checking the files out, your OS might apply some different modes to it, but Git itself only stores the ones above.

Comment: see my edit.  My os is Linux.  Do you get different permissions for that sequence?

Comment: @jthill You can see Git’s internal modes using `git ls-tree HEAD`.

Comment: @poke Yes, I know about that.  I'm reporting the actual filemodes I got on checkout with umask 0.